# How to iterate over div elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, puppeteer

I have tried all the ways to get all the text with [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) from each tweet, but I don't get what I want.

[image: tweets]

Strangely, it returns to me each letter from tweets one by one.

```
P
o
-----------------Scroll------------------------
w
undefined
a
-----------------Scroll------------------------
)
```

**UPDATE**

My code :

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
    await page.goto("https://twitter.com/search?q=linkedin&src=typeahead_click&f=top");

const tweets = await page.$$(".css-1dbjc4n.r-1loqt21.r-18u37iz.r-1ny4l3l.r-1udh08x.r-1qhn6m8.r-i023vh.r-o7ynqc.r-6416eg")

for (let i = 0; i < tweetsTexts.length; i++) { 
     const tweetsTexts = await (await tweets[i].getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue();
      if (i % 3 === 2) {
        await page.evaluate( () => {
          window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
      });
        await new Promise(function(resolve) { 
          setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
         });
        console.log("-----------------Scroll------------------------");
      }
      console.log(tweetsTexts[i]);

    } await browser.close();

}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the site as a [mcve].

Comment: `await (await` Whats this suppose to do?